# Inject code into compiled dll

Tags: c#, dll, unity-game-engine, reverse-engineering

I'm trying to figure out the inner workings of a C#/Unity program and examining the source code has given little to no results.

Is it possible to inject commands into the already compiled dll without the need of recompiling it which would take weeks of work to accomplish?

I would want some methods to output some of the data to a file I provide or maybe just signal that they were accessed so I can make more sense of the source.

Comment: If you have to source code I can't imagine how "injecting" code would be faster than using the source to meet your needs.  These type of hacks are rarely easy and "weeks" of work would be quick.  I expect working with the source will be faster.

Comment: I don't have the source code except the one that I can read from decompiling the dll. If I try to import it as a VS project I get about 50 000 error that need to get fixed. i managed to get about 48 000 of them with a script, but the rest seem to be syntax error that don't make sense since it was just decompiled from the same language.

Anyway, I'd be a lot easier just to have a little program that would weave command here and there that would manipulate the existing variables or print them in a file were I can view them. =)

Comment: ok in this case your question is misleading since de-compiling is **not** the same thing as having the source code.  Having the source code is having the source code -- which is what I thought you meant.  As for "fixing" errors the de-compiler gives you. Well there are lots of resources for information on how to de-compile -- but this website isn't one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are referring to Code Weaving. You can check the below projects:

1. [Fody](https://github.com/Fody/Fody)
2. [Mono Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/tools+libraries/libraries/Mono.Cecil/)